# How to zip multiple files with a max output size while keeping file pairs together

Tags: c#, batch-file, zip, cmd, 7zip

How would I zip up files into separate zip files totaling no more than a certain size, while keeping pairs of files together?

I would like to do this using a CLI with command prompt, a batch file, or with some C# code. I don't care if DotNetZip, 7Zip, or WinZip are used.

A sample scenario would be I have a Large Directory C:\LargeDirectory, 25 GB. This directory contains files that come in pairs. For example File1.pdf and File1.ind. These pairs need to stay together in each zip file. Each output zip file needs to stay below, lets say 2 GB.

Edit:
Their will be multiple pairs in each output zip. If one of the pairs would result in the output zip exceeding 2GB then they will be split off into another one.

Comment: What do you do if the two pairs end up being more than a certain size?

Comment: The files will not exceed the limit of the output zip, but if they both do not fit in one of the output zip files, they will both be put into the next one.

Comment: C# and DotNetZip will do the job. Good luck!

Comment: Do you want someone to produce a complete script/program for you or do you want to find out about particular things that you may need to accomplish the task? (Like, in batch scripting, for instance, how to generate a new name for your zip file or how to check a file's size or how to compare a value to another value.)

Comment: I was hoping to find a way to zip it like I posted in my C# code below, without breaking my zip file into parts, and keeping those files together. To tell you the truth I would have rather found a way to do it with a batch script.

Answer (score 3):

Here is some C# code that does the job based upon the requirements in the question. It zips up a directory of files into separate zip files totaling no more than a certain size, while keeping pairs of files together. In this case it is the two file types explicitly clarified in the code, but it can be made more general with a bit more customization. 
`private void CreateZip(string largeDir, string splitIntoDir, double maxFolderSize)
{
    int fileNumber = 1;
    List<String> files = new List<String>(Directory.GetFiles(largeDir, "*.pdf"));
    StringBuilder outputZip = new StringBuilder(splitIntoDir + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + Path.GetFileName(largeDir) + "_" + fileNumber + @".zip");
    double currentOutputSize = 0;
    List<String> toAdd = new List<String>();
    foreach (String file in files)
    {
        if(File.Exists(file) && File.Exists(file.Replace(".pdf", ".idf")))
            currentOutputSize += new FileInfo(file).Length + new FileInfo(file.Replace(".pdf", ".idf")).Length;`

```
    if (currentOutputSize &lt;= maxFolderSize)
    {
        toAdd.AddRange(new String[]{file, file.Replace(".pdf", ".idf")});

    }
    else
    {
        using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile(outputZip.ToString()))
        {
            foreach(String aFile in toAdd)
                zip.AddFile(aFile, "");
            zip.Save();
        }
        toAdd.Clear();
        fileNumber += 1;
        outputZip.Clear();
        outputZip.Append(splitIntoDir + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + Path.GetFileName(largeDir) + "_" + fileNumber + @".zip");
        currentOutputSize = new FileInfo(file).Length + new FileInfo(file.Replace(".pdf", ".idf")).Length;
        toAdd.Add(file);
    }
}
```

}
**Update:** Improved the speed of the algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

I have rewritten dkroy's algorithm because I think it does excessive casting and it queries the disks too often.

It now, loads all the files information in one shot, leaving the disk on peace until we need to write the zip files. Also I have optimized the comparison, it is being done on memory, using references instead of creating new objects every iteration, also changed some variables to standard .NET types and removing the StringBuilder, you can check the code:

```
private void CreateZip(string largeDir, string splitIntoDir, double maxFolderSize)
        {
            int fileNumber = 1;

            // We get all the PDFs and idf files at once
            FileInfo[] files = new DirectoryInfo(largeDir).GetFiles("*.pdf");
            FileInfo[] filesPair = new DirectoryInfo(largeDir).GetFiles("*.idf");

            List<FileInfo> toAdd = new List<FileInfo>();

            // We match on memory the filenames without extension and create an Anonymous object
            // which will contain both files

            var pairs = files.Join(filesPair, f => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f.FullName),
                idx => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(idx.FullName), (f, idx) => new {Pdf = f, Index = idx});

            long currentOutputSize = 0;
            string outputZip = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}_{3}.zip", splitIntoDir, Path.DirectorySeparatorChar, Path.GetFileName(largeDir), fileNumber);

            // iterate the pairs that matched the collection
            foreach (var pair in pairs)
            {
                // Sum the current pair of files
                currentOutputSize += pair.Pdf.Length + pair.Index.Length;

                if (currentOutputSize < maxFolderSize) 
                {
                    toAdd.Add(pair.Pdf);
                    toAdd.Add(pair.Index);
                }
                else
                {
                    using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile(outputZip))
                    { 
                        toAdd.ForEach(f=> zip.AddFile(f.FullName, string.Empty));
                        zip.Save();
                    }

                    // We start a new zip
                    toAdd.Clear();
                    fileNumber++;
                    currentOutputSize += pair.Pdf.Length + pair.Index.Length;
                    foutputZip = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}_{3}.zip", splitIntoDir, Path.DirectorySeparatorChar, Path.GetFileName(largeDir), fileNumber);

                    // We add the current iteration's files
                    toAdd.Add(pair.Pdf);
                    toAdd.Add(pair.Index);
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe that you are hoping to split the archive into several equal parts. This can be done through the use of 7-zip and batch.

To split the archive into equal size:

```
@echo off
@set "ZipPath=%ProgramFiles%\7-Zip\7z.exe"
@IF NOT EXIST "%ZipPath%" set "ZipPath=%ProgramFiles(x86)%\7-Zip\7z.exe"

"%ZipPath%" a -mx9 -mmt4 -m0=lzma:d27:fb128 -v2g "C:\foo.7z" "C:\LargeDirectory"

PAUSE
```

This will split the archive into two 2GB each. To extract the archive:

```
@echo off

@set "ZipPath=%ProgramFiles%\7-Zip\7z.exe"
@IF NOT EXIST "%ZipPath%" set "ZipPath=%ProgramFiles(x86)%\7-Zip\7z.exe"

"%ZipPath%" x "-oC:\LargeDirectory" "C:\foo.7z.001"

PAUSE
```

You may also refer to [7-zip command-line](http://www.dotnetperls.com/7-zip-examples) for more information. Hope it helps.